# Как задать блокам с float: left высоту контейнера

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, float

Есть некие блоки обернутые в контейнер. Имеют свойство float: left . Нужно, чтобы они были высотой с контейнер (height: 100% - не работает). Clearfix задан. Высота контейнера не задана(по самому высокому блоку внутри выставляется автоматически).
Не используя flex и table

Comment: при чем тут `float: left` и высота контейнера?

Comment: Блоки стоят в ряд

Comment: выложи сюда код, чтобы можно было иметье представление, что ты там творишь...

Comment: Прийду домой, выложу. Спасибо за понимание.

Answer (score 2):

Свойство height, указанное в %, работает только если у родительского блока указана высота, либо если элементы абсолютно позиционированы.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [flex](https://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Он умеет делать все тоже самое что и флоат( в большинстве случаев) и даже больше. Да и проблем с ним меньше. Поддержка хорошая, дерзайте. 
Второй(более старый вариант) можно попробовать использовать display: table, table-row, table-cell... Но первый вариант лучше.

Comment: Я знаю про flexbox. Просто он не везде поддерживается. А табличный устарел. Если есть другой способ, подскажите.

Comment: @Letton, например? https://caniuse.com/#search=flex, мне кажется это хороший показатель

Comment: @Letton, https://caniuse.com/#search=table (2 вариант)

Comment: Спасибо, что подсказали про table

Comment: Node_pro, у IE 9 и ниже будут проблемы с flex. Но специально для них можно сделать это таблицой. Ещё раз спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Что вам мешало использовать `height: inherit;`?

```css
main {
height: 100px;
}
div {
float: left;
width: 100px;
margin-right: 10px;
height: inherit;
background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Добавь текст в блоки

Comment: @Letton о том, что высота контейнера не задана вроде как позже появилось. А про разную высоту блока не уточняется. Случаи бывают разные. При динамически обновляемом контенте вам нужен либо JS, либо все же flexbox, поддержка которого уже добралась к 97%. Поддерживая старые браузеры, вы сами тормозите внедрения новшеств, облегчающих вам жизнь.